# How to have a setup chunk both in the parent and a child document?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I usually split my r-markdown document into `master.rmd` and several `child.rmd` documents. I first work on each `child.rmd` document as a standalone document. While at it, it is convenient to have a `setup` chunk in `child.rmd` so that RStudio knows to run it before any other chunk. The problem arises when I then include `child.rmd` into `master.rmd` which also has a `setup` chunk.

Is there a way to have `setup` chunks both in the parent and the child documents?

My documents usually look something like this:

`master.rmd`:

````
---
title: "master"
output: html_document
params:
  standalone: no
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

`child.rmd`:

````
---
title: "child"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
params:
  standalone: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, eval=params$standalone}
library(stats)
```    

```{r}
if (params$standalone) {
  plot(cars)
} else {
  plot(iris)
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

What does the `standalone:` YAML setting do?

When messing with your code, I encounter an error that your `child` and `master` had the same chunk names ("setup"). So to help R, make your R chunks unique names.

Here is what I did, to run the `master.Rmd` and have it generate what is in `child.Rmd`. I tried to make the code more simple for myself to be able to try and see if I can help. Please let me know if this helps you decipher your Rmarkdown issue. These files are in the exact same directory

*master.rmd*

````
---
title: "master"
output: html_document
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE, child='child.Rmd'}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

*child.rmd*

````
---
title: "child"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup1, include=TRUE}
library(stats)

if (TRUE) {
  plot(cars)
} else {
  plot(iris)
}
```
````

Below is the output I get when I run the `master.rmd` file
[image]

Comment: "What does the standalone: YAML setting do?"

It lets me run different code depending on whether I'm knitting `child.rmd` as a standalone file or as a part of `master.rmd`. For example, it lets me run the `setup` chunk in `child.rmd` only when it is knitted as a standalone file (see `eval=params$standalone` chunk parameter). I included the `params: standalone` YAML node here in case someone knows how to exclude the setup chunk altogether using such a parameter.

Comment: "make your R chunks unique names". That is actually the crux of my problem:I would like to keep `setup` chunks both in `child.rmd` and `master.rmd` because the `setup` chunk has a special role when you work with r-markdown in RStudio. As you noted, this does not work the way I am doing it in the sample code. I was hoping there was a way around this, however. E.g., have a chunk that changes its name depending on the value of `params$standalone`.